# Alternatives to decorator pattern when decorators have to return different things

Tags: decorator

Imagine that when I receive a request from a browser, with that request I have to save this object to ddbb, send an email to some people with the information of the request and post this request to an forum. I have been thinking about three posibilities:

1. With decorator pattern. I could use this but in this case I dont have a main object to decorate to and the decorators have to return different things so this pattern doesnt work for me
2. With a list of classes(each one has one functionality, send and email, save to ddbb...) that implement one interface and I iterate this list calling their methods but once again the classes have to return different things so this pattern doesnt work for me
3. Other pattern useful for this case?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you working with? Or is this a generic, language-agnostic question?

Comment: I am working in java but its a language-agnostic question